# How can I use a public array from my Model in my Seeder to insert values in my table?

Tags: php, laravel, model, migration, associative-array

I have a Model called Browser which has an array of all the browsers.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Browser extends Model
{
    const CHROME = 'chrome';
    const FIREFOX = 'firefox';
    const OPERA = 'opera';
    const SAFARI = 'safari';
    const MICROSOFTEDGE = 'microsoft edge';
    const INTERNETEXPLORER = 'internet explorer';
    public static $types = [self::CHROME, self::FIREFOX, self::OPERA, self::SAFARI, self::MICROSOFTEDGE, self::INTERNETEXPLORER];
}
```

And I have a Seeder that fills the browsers table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BrowserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('browsers')->insert(array(
            array('name' => 'chrome'),
            array('name' => 'firefox'),
            array('name' => 'opera'),
            array('name' => 'safari'),
            array('name' => 'microsoft edge'),
            array('name' => 'internet explorer'),
            array('name' => 'other'),
        ));
    }
}
```

Could I use the $types array from my Browser model to inset into the database? Because to insert you need an associative array, and I would like to keep $types as it is. Could I easily convert it to an associative array in my Seeder without needing an array with the keys but with just 1 key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BrowserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $arr = array_map( function( $el ) {
            return array('name' => $el );
        }, App\Browser::$types );

        DB::table('browsers')->insert($arr);
    }
}
```

It's of course not necesary to store in `$arr` but this makes it a little more readable I think.

Comment: Works but the two parameters of the array_map need to be switched

Comment: True, I always get those mixed up as for example array_filter is the other way round. Cheers mate